# Getting OAuth access token in Explara API

Tags: django, oauth

I'm  trying to get an access token for explara API using an Django application using the following code. It's working fine for getting code. After getting code when it goes to else part of get_explara_token view; give the error **'{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}'** while I has defined grant type as authorization_code as mentioned in Explara API documentation here http://developers.explara.com/get-api-access

**views.py**

```
import requests
import urllib
def get_explara_token(request):

    access_code = request.GET.get('code')

    if access_code is None:
        code = 'code'
        state = 'event'        
    query = {
            'response_type':code,
            'client_id': EXPLARA_CLIENT_ID,
            'state':state
        }

        url = 'https://account.explara.com/account/oauth/authorize?%s' % urllib.urlencode(query)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    else:

    url = 'https://account.explara.com/account/oauth/token/' + 'client_id=' + str(EXPLARA_CLIENT_ID) + '&client_secret=' + str(EXPLARA_CLIENT_SECRET) + '&grant_type=' + 'authorization_code' + '&code=' + str(access_code)
        response = requests.post(url)
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post data in that way:

```
requests.post('https://account.explara.com/account/oauth/token', data={'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'client_id': 123123123, 'client_secret': '123123123', 'code': '123123'}).content
```

Instead of that you tried to pass data via GET parameters.